# How do I order two GUIDs as the lowest first?

Tags: c#

I have 2 GUIDs - guid1 & guid2. I want to combined them into one guid, by ordering the lowest one first.

So I will do:

```
if(Guid1.Length != Guid2.Length)
{
    if (Guid1.Length > Guid2.Length)
        return Guid2 + Guid1;
    else
        return Guid1 + Guid2;
}
else
{
    var isDiff = true;
    var index = Guid1.Length - 1;
    while(isDiff)
    {
        if (index < 0) // same guids
            return Guid1 + Guid2;

        if(Guid1[index] == Guid2[index])
        {
            index--;
        }
        else
        {
            // Here stuck
        }

    }
}
```

At the commented part, I want to check each character whether it is a number or a letter and find which is the lowest, then concatenate and return the string with the lowest one first.

Example:

guid1 = "ab12";
guid2 = "a21c";

So I am thinking each string character could be turned into its ASCII equivalent and then the lowest value is found.

For my example, the returned string would be:

guid1 + guid2 = "ab12a21c"

because the decimal value for the second characters are 32 (for number 2) and 98 (for b).

is this the best approach? If so, how do I convert to ASCII in c#?

Comment: What's your definition of "lowest"?

Comment: Also it seems your "guid" is a string. Why not use the [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) structure instead? Then you can compare them more easily, and just pick the lower one (the structure implements `IComparable`)

Comment: @HonzaBrestan if I'm not mistaken my user Ids generated by MVC Identity are strings in the DB. I will double check this.

Comment: @UweKeim the lowest deemed however. I am making a standard function. In my example it would be the lowest value obtained from converting the strings to decimal values as per the ASCII table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Guids have the same length.Also you can use the CompareTo method as in the following example.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Guid g1 = Guid.Parse("c47632a3-274b-44d0-93df-f9626a033a6f");
        Guid g2 = Guid.Parse("c47632a3-274b-43d0-93df-f9626a033a6f");
        Console.WriteLine(g1);
        Console.WriteLine(g2);
        Console.WriteLine(GetResult(g1,g2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string GetResult(Guid Guid1, Guid Guid2)
    {
        return Guid1.CompareTo(Guid2) < 0 ? Guid1.ToString() + Guid2.ToString() : Guid2.ToString() + Guid1.ToString();
    }
}

}
```

In the above example g2 comes first.
          If you change "43d0" to "45d0" g1 will come first
Isn't this what you need?